# How to create module in Magento Open Source 2.4.4?

Tags: magento-community, magento-ce, magento2.4.4, magentomodule, magento-admin

1. How to create Backend module form in magento 2.
2. How to save data in database
3. how to create menu.xml
4. How to Create Module,view and Controller Layers
5. How to create Magento 2.4.4 custom grid
6. Why we create phtml file.
7. How to create admin form using layout and UI component with save data and redirect to grid ?
8. How to create Magento CLI command
9. How to ACL file file and what is purpose of ACL file
   10.What is purpose of DataProvider.php and where is created DataProvider file ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's name the module `StackExchange_HelloWorld`.
you will need these files:

`app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/registration.php` - the registration file

```
<?php 
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'StackExchange_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

`app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml` - the module declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="StackExchange_HelloWorld" setup_version="2.0.0" />
</config>
```

`app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml` - the frontend routing file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="StackExchange_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

`app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php` - the index controller

```
<?php 
namespace StackExchange\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
     protected $resultPageFactory;
     public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
         $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
         $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Hello World'));
         return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

`app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml` - the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="StackExchange_HelloWorld::index.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

`app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/index.phtml` - the template for the block

```
 <h2>Hello World</h2>
```

after you are done, run this in the console

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

You should be able to see the result at the url `[ROOT]/helloworld`

You added another questions too. please ask questions sepratly in stackexchange so people can answer you one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this article and create admin module with CRUD.

https://webkul.com/blog/create-collection-grid-editadd-grid-row-installer-magento2/